# Real laminations on a 4-punctured sphere

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Fix a triangulation $T$ of the 4-punctured sphere.  (Formally, an *ideal* triangulation, but taking a combinatorial viewpoint, we may as well just fix a triangulation of the sphere with 4 vertices and call those vertices punctures.)

Thurston proved (in much greater generality than this) that the rational unbounded measured laminations of the 4-punctured sphere are in bijection with $\mathbb{Q}^6$.  The map takes a lamination to its shear coordinates with respect to $T$.

Such a lamination is a collection of pairwise non-intersecting, pairwise non-isotopic, non-self-intersecting curves satisfying certain restrictions, each having a rational weight.  If we extend the definition by simply allowing real weights, the shear coordinates of the resulting laminations fail to cover $\mathbb{R}^6$.

My question is, what is the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^6$ left uncovered?  I suspect that someone has already worked this out.

I (with coauthors) am able to find a 2-dimensional (rational) plane in which every irrational ray is left uncovered.  We think there should be no other points left uncovered, but the proof does not seem easy, and we wondered if anyone has already worked this out.

By the way, my motivation for this comes, tangentially, from cluster algebras, starting with work by Fomin, Shapiro and Thurston, where the laminations are encoding the dynamics of coefficients.